# Creating quadtree index on latitude, longitude data in PostGIS

Tags: postgis, quadtree

I have a table of locations in which one of the columns represents the lat-long for the location.  These coordinates have been extracted from the OpenStreetMap file. How can I create a quadtree index on these coordinates using PostGIS?

Comment: Why do you want that?

Comment: We are trying to grid the map for a project and want to use quadtree index.

Comment: I believe you can do this with the pg-gist extension to Postgres -- but it probably won't be very easy, see: https://www.pgcon.org/2011/schedule/attachments/197_pgcon-2011.pdf. It would be reasonably straightforward to write you own, although getting the optimizer to use it would be trickier.

Comment: @JohnBarça The link you gave mentions SP-Gist. http://doxygen.postgresql.org/spgquadtreeproc_8c.html shows that there is an implementation for quadtree in SP-GiST. But I am unable to find a documentation or examples of how to use it for creating index.

Comment: There is a link on last page to https://www.cs.purdue.edu/spgist/. Look at the documents tab. I have never attempted this, it is just something I remember coming across, and not being a C programmer, running away from.